# What happened to The Bulletin’s digital archive?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015

In Season 2 Episode 5 of Daredevil, Ellison allows Karen to look through *The Bulletin’s* archives in exchange for a story on the Punisher.

To Karen’s dismay, all the digital archives were lost.

> Ellison: All the servers were completely wiped in the incident. Decades, just gone. So we keep hard copies of everything now.

What incident is Ellison referring to? How did *The Bulletin* lose their digital archive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it was the events of the first Avengers movie. "The Incident" is referred to several times in the show, and it seems to be referring to when the Chitauri invaded New York.

Comment: How do aliens invading result in a server wipe?

Comment: @Thunderforge - EMP from the nuke?  Dreadfully unstable power grid due to the epic war zone?

Comment: Massive power surge in the Chrysler Building data center after being struck by Thunder God lightning?